# Null Pointer Exception When changing ImageView src from code

Tags: android, exception, imageview

I am trying to create fragments for a ViewPageAdapter for swipping beetwin 6 different images 
Here is my code :

```
package com.example.newyorkfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CatalogActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 6;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.catalog_pager);



        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects, in
     * sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            ImageView catalogImage;
            catalogImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.catalogImageSlide);
            switch (position){
            case 0:
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position), 200).show();
                catalogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_1_12_tel);
                break;
            }

        case 1:
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position++), 200).show();
            catalogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_2_11);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position++), 200).show();
            catalogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_3_10);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position++), 200).show();
            catalogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_4_9);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position++), 200).show();
            catalogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_5_8);
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position++), 200).show();
            catalogImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.page_6_7);
            break;
        }}

            return new CatalogFragment() ;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a null pointer error in my switch case , i think i am defining the catalogImage in wrong prace in my code but i cannot find an answere

```
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at com.example.newyorkfinal.CatalogActivity$ScreenSlidePagerAdapter.getItem(CatalogActivity.java:81)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:105)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:829)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:979)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2472)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5287)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
09-13 17:31:30.170: E/AndroidRuntime(17862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

catalog_slide.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/BurlyWood" >


    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/contentCatalog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/catalogImageSlide"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/page_1_12_tel" />

</ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

catalog_pager.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

CatalogFragment.java

```
package com.example.newyorkfinal;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CatalogFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.catalog_slide, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat error? Would be far easier for people to help, if we had the output. :)

Comment: Which line is throwing the NPE?

Comment: It's the catalogImage that null?

Answer (score 2):

You should add an argument to CatalogFragment that takes in the image resource required to be loaded. And load the imageview in CatalogFragment.

Currently you are changing some random imageview and then loading the CatalogFragment which knows nothing of the ImageView nor the resource it's meant to load.

Comment: I would have to agree with Pork, this job should be handled by the Fragment. You could inflate the imageView based off the ID that you pass to it on getView()

Comment: Can you provide some further info of how to do this? Its the first time i use page adapter and I am totally lost...